# Multiple users in DVC

Tags: dvc

I would like to ask if it is possible to use DVC with several accounts on the same machine. At the moment, all commands (`dvc pull`, `dvc push`, ...) are executed under my name. But after several people joined this project too, I do not want them to execute commands under my name.

When I was alone on this project I generated ssh key:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Connected to server where DVC remote data is stored:

```
ssh-copy-id username@server_IP
```

Created config file which lets me execute all `dvc` commands using ssh:

```
[core]
    remote = storage_server
['remote "storage_server"']
    url = ssh://username@server_IP:/home/DVC_remote/DVC_project
```

What I should do so that several people could execute commands on their own name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the "username" part of the config personalized based on who is running the command. There are a few options to do this (based on [this document](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/modify#available-parameters-per-storage-type), see the SSH part):

### Basic options are:

- User defined in the SSH config file (e.g. `~/.ssh/config`) for this host (URL);
- Current system user;

So, the simplest even options could be just remove it from the URL and rely on the current system user?

### Local (git-ignored or per-project DVC config) config

You could do is to remove the `username` part from the `url` and run something like this:

```
dvc remote modify --local storage_server user username
```

`--local` here means that DVC will create a separate additional config that will be ignored by Git. This way if every user runs this command in every project they use they will customize the username.

---

Let me know if that helps or something doesn't work. I'll try to help.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, I created local config entry. However, when I deleted my SSH key files (because I do not want others to use my SSH), when I do `dvc push -r example` I receive error saying permission denied. Is there a way to tell DVC to ask for a password?

Comment: I would try `dvc remote modify storage_server ask_password true` ... I would though try to use SSH still. You can secure SSH files to be accessible only to you - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257590/ssh-key-permissions-chmod-settings/595537 . SSH is still the best and the most secure way to go.